# Python asyncio websocket ConnectionClosed

Tags: python, task

i have multiple tasks that use websocket. i would like to detect the connection close of websocket and then reconnect the websocket, I'm doing it through a variable called break_task if it is true then in on of the task there was a connection close detection, below the code and the error exception I got (i use python 3.6):

break_task = False

```
async def value_1():
    global break_task
    msg_dict = deepcopy(MESG)
    async with websockets.connect('wss://api.xxxxx') as ws:
        await ws.send(json.dumps(msg_dict))
        while break_task == False:
            try:
                res = await ws.recv()
            except ConnectionClosed:
                print('CONNECTION CLOSED raised exception in value_1() -> TRYING TO RECONNECT !!!')
                break_task = True
                break

async def value_2():
    global break_task
    auth_dict = deepcopy(PAYLOAD)   
    async with websockets.connect('wss://api.xxxxx') as ws:
        await ws.send(json.dumps(auth_dict))
        while break_task == False:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.05)
            try:
                res = await ws.recv()
            except ConnectionClosed:
                print('CONNECTION CLOSED raised exception in value_2() -> TRYING TO RECONNECT !!!')
                break_task = True
                break
            data = json.loads(res)
```

and...

```
while True:   
    if (break_task == False):
        tasks = value_1(), value_2()
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
    elif (break_task == True):
        tasks = None
        loop.stop()
        loop.close()
        break_task = False
```

I get this result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tija_v0.1.py", line 584, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
  File "C:\Dev\Anaconda2\envs\python36\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 589, in gather
    fut = ensure_future(arg, loop=loop)
  File "C:\Dev\Anaconda2\envs\python36\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 513, in ensure_future
    task = loop.create_task(coro_or_future)
  File "C:\Dev\Anaconda2\envs\python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 282, in create_task
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Dev\Anaconda2\envs\python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 357, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'value_2' was never awaited
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'value_1' was never awaited
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are stopping and closing the event loop when break_task is True?  One possible case is that you stop and close the event loop, and then when you call asyncio.get_event_loop() you are getting the same closed event loop.  I think you need to re-open and start it.

Comment: the reason is because a websocket disconnection was detected and i whish to restart the connection so i stop then i close the connection and within the while True when break_task is True I reopen. I'm doing something wrong ?

Comment: Please can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'value_2' was never awaited
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'value_1' was never awaited

might trip your process from reconnecting, it might effect in more severe way than a warning. I have similar problem when attempting to bind async message update_handler function to synchronic third party web socket message handler.

You should find a method to call the handler with await to prevent this warning.